# How to retrieve user details from database and display in a view [MVC 5 application,,Identity User]

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-6.1

I just started creating an mvc 5 application ,I'm using default Identity user database for user data management,But I added some more fields like First Name ,Last Name ,Email Id to this database using migration,Now I need to display this all detail in a view page (as a profile page) ,but I don't know how to retrieve Identity user data from default database ,I am a new mvc developer can you help me

**my model class**

```
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManageUserViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        [Remote("CheckUserNameExists", "Common")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DbContextClass**

```
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: *IdentityUser* object is singleton db context. It should be available through out app like other default fields. Have you checked this fact ?

Comment: Can you show me a simple controller example  to retrieve FirstName of current user from database

Comment: What i meant to say, user context should be available dynamically without any implementation. If you can align mvc default boilerplate code, you can see that there is no code written for default fields for user context. Can you please check [this article](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create a detail view of your class from the controller and let it scaffold and return user detail to your view. Import `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` to identify the current user and use it in your linq statement 
E.g.

```
[Authorize()]
ActionResult Details()
{
  var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
  var comp = db.AspNetUsers.Where(i => i.UserName== UserId).First();

  return View(comp);
}
```

Hope it helps