# ASP.NET Identity Foreign Key as Primary key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, primary-key, asp.net-identity, database-migration

In my ASP.NET MVC Application, I customized the Identity to use another table for storing the users' infos such as first name, last name and birthdate. Here's the association code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public virtual UserInfo Info { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set;
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

But **how do you use the primary key of the ApplicationUser class as the primary key of UserInfo so that you know which user accounts the infos belong to?**

Comment: this may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467649/how-to-retrieve-user-details-from-database-and-display-in-a-view-mvc-5-applicat

Comment: That didn't help. That doesn't have any answers yet. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The primary Key of `ApplicationUser` will be of a default type `String`, so first you will need to change your dependent class to also have a key of type string.

```
public class UserInfo
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set;
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your IdentityDbContext implementation you will need to create a mapping to create the 1:1 relationship you are after like so.

```
public class MyIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(x => x.Info).WithRequiredDependent();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

and that should work